# WPF interactivity event trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, ribbon

First the code that is causing the issue:

```
<my:Ribbon x:Name="ribbon">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RibbonTabSelectedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <my:RibbonTab Header="Chart" Tag="Chart"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedSearchResult, 
                  Converter={StaticResource nullToBoolConverter}}">
        <my:RibbonGroup>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSearchResult.Values}" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFrequency, Mode=TwoWay}">

            </ComboBox>
        </my:RibbonGroup>
    </my:RibbonTab>
</my:Ribbon>
```

What I want to do is handle the SelectionChanged of a RibbonTab using MvvmLight framework, and convert the event to a view model command. It works great.
The problem is that after adding the ComboBox, the selection changed of a combobox is handled also by this code. And I don't want that to happend. The Ribbon is the one from Microsoft WPF Ribbon.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" SourceName="ribbon" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=ribbon}" >
```

any ideas? Thanks!